# SCHEDULER_API support is not yet available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

"SCHEDULER_API support is not yet available."

when i am trying to delete redshift cluster using redshift aws sdk got the above error,,i am not sure if i have to upgrade pakage have used the following code

Amazon.Redshift.Model.DescribeClustersRequest describeClustersRequest = new Amazon.Redshift.Model.DescribeClustersRequest();
Amazon.Redshift.Model.DescribeClustersResponse describeClustersResponse = clientRedshift.DescribeClusters(describeClustersRequest);
List<Amazon.Redshift.Model.Cluster> redshiftClusters = describeClustersResponse.Clusters;

```
            if (redshiftClusters.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Amazon.Redshift.Model.Cluster cluster in redshiftClusters)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var deleteRequest = new Amazon.Redshift.Model.DeleteClusterRequest()
                        {
                            ClusterIdentifier = cluster.ClusterIdentifier,
                            SkipFinalClusterSnapshot = true
                        };

                        var deleteResponse = clientRedshift.DeleteCluster(deleteRequest);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the boto3 library with updated AWS CLI on your machine to delete redshift clusters. Follow the official documentation from here (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift/client/delete_cluster.html)

Best!
Sai Teja